# Swift: Is it possible to conditionally declare variables?

Tags: swift

Let's say there is a `struct` with two variables: `a` and `b`.

It is possible to declare one of the two variables and ignore the other based on a condition?

In other words, is it possible from this `struct`:

```
struct example {
    let a: Int
    let b: Int
}
```

To do this:

```
struct example {
    if (condition) {
        let a: Int
    } else {
        let b: Int
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for this?

Comment: The reason is I need to avoid declaring too many optional variables.

Comment: Then better to create two different struct or set default values.

Comment: @RajaKishan It is difficult to set default values for such variables: `let mainView: () -> MainContent` (note: `MainContent` is a `View`) Unless, there is a way I'm unaware of.

Comment: If you are sure whenever using this var is not nil then you can declare like this ```let mainView: (() -> MainContent)!```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible, because if you did this, what would this code do:

```
let e = exampleReturningFunction()
print(e.a)
```

If `condition` is false, should this crash? Should `a` have some default value? What value? (If so, just use a default value in the struct.)

In most cases, what you really want here is an enum with associated data:

```
enum Example {
    case a(Int)
    case b(Int)
}
```

If there are many related properties, you can group them together:

```
struct A { ... }
struct B { ... }

enum Example {
    case a(A)
    case b(B)
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I organized the variables inside `struct`s and used an `enum` to determine which variable set to initialize. Clever solution!